# API map yandex. Получение данных ymaps.geocode и их дальнейшая обработка

Tags: yandex-maps-api, geocode

Есть список точек маршрутов

```
var routes =[["Новосибирск-главный","Сочи"],
["Новосибирск-главный","Сочи"], 
["Новосибирск-главный","Москва (Ярославский вокзал)","Москва (Казанский вокзал)","Сочи"],];
```

по ним я получаю координаты и ставлю точки на карту:

```
 $.each(routes, function (key1, item1) {
        $.each(item1, function (key, item) {
            ymaps.geocode(item, {results: 1}).then(function (res) {

                var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                // Координаты геобъекта.
                var c = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();
                coords [coords.length] = c;
                //coords[key1][key] = c;
                var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(c, {

                        balloonContent: item
                    }, {
                        preset: 'islands#redIcon',

                    }
                );
                myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

                myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange: true});
                return coords;

            })
```

Но точки получаю асинхронно и в дальнейшем не могу построить кривую маршрута. Кто сталкивался с вопросом и какие могут быть варианты решения?

Comment: а почему просто не строите маршрут по адресам? Как тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving

Comment: @reni по факту у меня ж не маршрут, а направление всего лишь. Т.е. мне не надо маршрут по дороге строить, всего лишь задать ломаную. Но за совет спасибо. Может быть удастся как-то привязаться.

Comment: В таком случае Вы можете проверять количество точек на карте в then и если уже все появились (на карте столько же меток, сколько адресов в массиве), то вызывать метод построения линии.